# How to disable JSON schema in Kafka Source Connector (e.g. Debezium)

Tags: apache-kafka, jsonschema, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I followed Debezium tutorial (https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/tree/master/tutorial#using-postgres) and all received CDC data from Postgres are sent to Kafka topic in JSON format with schema - **how to get rid of schema?**

Here is config of connector (launched in Docker container)

```
{
    "name": "inventory-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "database.hostname": "postgres",
        "database.port": "5432",
        "database.user": "postgres",
        "database.password": "postgres",
        "database.dbname" : "postgres",
        "database.server.name": "dbserver1",
        "schema.include": "inventory"
    }
}
```

The JSON schema is still in message.
I managed to get rid of it only when launched Docker container with following environment variables:

```
 - CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMAS_ENABLE=false
 - CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMAS_ENABLE=false
```

**Why I cannot achieve exactly the same from connector configuration?**

Example of Kafka message with schema:

```
{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"int32","optional":false,"field":"id"}],"optional":false,"name":"dbserver1.inventory.customers.Key"},"payload":{"id":1001}}    {"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"int32","optional":false,"field":"id"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"first_name"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"last_name"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"email"}],"optional":true,"name":"dbserver1.inventory.customers.Value","field":"before"},{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"int32","optional":false,"field":"id"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"first_name"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"last_name"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"email"}],"optional":true,"name":"dbserver1.inventory.customers.Value","field":"after"},{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"version"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"connector"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"name"},{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"ts_ms"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"name":"io.debezium.data.Enum","version":1,"parameters":{"allowed":"true,last,false"},"default":"false","field":"snapshot"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"db"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"schema"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"table"},{"type":"int64","optional":true,"field":"txId"},{"type":"int64","optional":true,"field":"lsn"},{"type":"int64","optional":true,"field":"xmin"}],"optional":false,"name":"io.debezium.connector.postgresql.Source","field":"source"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"op"},{"type":"int64","optional":true,"field":"ts_ms"},{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"id"},{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"total_order"},{"type":"int64","optional":false,"field":"data_collection_order"}],"optional":true,"field":"transaction"}],"optional":false,"name":"dbserver1.inventory.customers.Envelope"},"payload":{"before":null,"after":{"id":1001,"first_name":"Sally","last_name":"Thomas","email":"sally.thomas@acme.com"},"source":{"version":"1.4.1.Final","connector":"postgresql","name":"dbserver1","ts_ms":1611918971029,"snapshot":"true","db":"postgres","schema":"inventory","table":"customers","txId":602,"lsn":34078720,"xmin":null},"op":"r","ts_ms":1611918971032,"transaction":null}}
```

Example (**desired** by me) w/o schema:

```
{"id":1001} {"before":null,"after":{"id":1001,"first_name":"Sally","last_name":"Thomas","email":"sally.thomas@acme.com"},"source":{"version":"1.4.1.Final","connector":"postgresql","name":"dbserver1","ts_ms":1611920304594,"snapshot":"true","db":"postgres","schema":"inventory","table":"customers","txId":597,"lsn":33809448,"xmin":null},"op":"r","ts_ms":1611920304596,"transaction":null}
```

Debezium container is run with following command:

```
docker run -it --name connect -p 8083:8083 -e GROUP_ID=1 -e CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs -e OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets -e STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_statuses -e CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMAS_ENABLE=false -e CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMAS_ENABLE=false --link zookeeper:zookeeper --link kafka:kafka --link mysql:mysql debezium/connect:1.3
```

or as docker-compose

```
  connect:
    image: debezium/connect:${DEBEZIUM_VERSION}
    ports:
     - 8083:8083
    links:
     - kafka
     - postgres
    environment:
     - BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092
     - GROUP_ID=1
     - CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs
     - OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets
     - STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_statuses
     - CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMAS_ENABLE=false
     - CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMAS_ENABLE=false
```

`CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMAS_ENABLE=false` and `CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMAS_ENABLE=false` was added later by me, but without them I cannot get rid of schema.

`connect` docker container (Kafka connectors servers cluster - if I understood it correctly) is started without any connector.
I create it manually.

LOGs from docker-compose for connect when connector created

```
connect_1    | 2021-01-29 18:04:57,395 INFO   ||  JsonConverterConfig values: 
connect_1    |  converter.type = key
connect_1    |  decimal.format = BASE64
connect_1    |  schemas.cache.size = 1000
connect_1    |  schemas.enable = true
connect_1    |    [org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverterConfig]
connect_1    | 2021-01-29 18:04:57,396 INFO   ||  Set up the key converter class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter for task inventory-connector-0 using the worker config   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
connect_1    | 2021-01-29 18:04:57,396 INFO   ||  JsonConverterConfig values: 
connect_1    |  converter.type = value
connect_1    |  decimal.format = BASE64
connect_1    |  schemas.cache.size = 1000
connect_1    |  schemas.enable = true
connect_1    |    [org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverterConfig]
...
connect_1    | 2021-01-29 18:04:57,458 INFO   ||  Starting PostgresConnectorTask with configuration:   [io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask]
connect_1    | 2021-01-29 18:04:57,460 INFO   ||     key.converter.schemas.enable = false   [io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask]
connect_1    | 2021-01-29 18:04:57,460 INFO   ||     value.converter.schemas.enable = false   [io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask]
```

Here are get connector command output:

```
$ curl -i http://localhost:8083/connectors/inventory-connector

{"name":"inventory-connector","config":{"connector.class":"io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",**"key.converter.schemas.enable":"false"**,"database.user":"postgres","database.dbname":"postgres","tasks.max":"1","database.hostname":"postgres","database.password":"postgres",**"value.converter.schemas.enable":"false"**,"name":"inventory-connector","database.server.name":"dbserver1","database.port":"5432","schema.include":"inventory"},"tasks":[{"connector":"inventory-connector","task":0}],"type":"source"}
```

Comment: Please provide your docker run command

Comment: Maybe you should explicitly add the json converter if you intend to use the schemas enabled config in the connector. In my experience, that works just fine

Comment: Yeah, `"value.converter.schemas.enable": "false"` should work just fine. Maybe the config didn't take, or the messages you viewed were from a different topic? Either way, you can validate in the Kafka Connect worker log what settings were in effect. But they can definitely be overridden in the connector config JSON itself.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt, I even from the very start changed docker with schema disabled and it doesn't work :(
And if I get c connector config via REST http.../connectors/connector-name it returns me schema disabled, but I still see them in topic (I have one single topic) :)
I'll re-check logs and update

Comment: @RobinMoffatt, LOGs and extra-info added

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I reproduced [this](https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/tree/master/tutorial#using-postgres) example. As @OneCricketeer mentioned in the comment, you have to explicitly add [`JsonConverter`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.7/connect/json/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/json/JsonConverter.java):

```
{
    "name": "inventory-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "database.hostname": "postgres",
        "database.port": "5432",
        "database.user": "postgres",
        "database.password": "postgres",
        "database.dbname" : "postgres",
        "database.server.name": "dbserver1",
        "schema.include": "inventory"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it works, thx, but in the past I added already 
"key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter" (and the same for value) and it also didn't work (for MySql DB - but I don't think DB is the issue) - maybe I did something wrong last time. Now I tried one more time and it works